# bootstrap 3.3.2: new glyphicons missing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have installed the latest bootstrap 3.3.2 from scratch, but the new glyphicons like glyphicon-duplicate are missing.

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="contact_copy"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate" aria-hidden="true"></span> Copy</a></li>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Michael

Comment: Can you post an example of code where glyphicons don't render?

Comment: Verify that your site is actually using the correct, latest font files.

Comment: Hi cvrebert, yes, all bootstrap 3.3.2 files are from 18./19. Jan 2015.

Comment: i can not reproduce your issue, also see: http://www.bootply.com/4xajVocPwb

Comment: I searched again, I have includes the 'bootstrap-theme.min.css' instead of 'bootstrap.min.css'. Sorry and thank you Bass

Comment: I have this issue also, but my set up was generated with yeoman angular-fullstack, with bower, and I can't see how to fix my imports to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Clear browser cache?  Check developer toolbox for any 404s on page load?